# What should be used after plural nouns. makes or make?

Tags: verbs, nouns, plural-forms

Which one of the following is correct?

> 1) The things **makes** it look beautiful.
>   2) The things **make** it look
>   beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Second is correct, as plural verbs don't end in an "s."

"The things make it look beautiful."
([Source](https://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Blue%20Level/B31_Plural.html))